# Can my company view my PAST browsing history of what I've done at home with *my personal* computer and *my personal* network?

Tags: privacy

This is if I later on connect my personal computer to the company network?

I don't browse anything non-work related using the computer network on my personal computer at work, and I am aware that they can see what I have browsed while I am on their network even though it is with my own computer.

Comment: Unless you've installed some form of company spyware, or give your company access to the files on your computer, the answer is really no.

Comment: They probably can't even see what you're browsing at work if you haven't installed any corporate software and the green HTTPS lock is there in your browser.

Answer (score 1):

No. Your history is not actively communicating for anything to be seen - hence the name "history".  If this were a work computer, it would potentially be a different answer because they could have logging or monitoring software to track its activity and upload the "history" as soon as you connected it back to the office network.  Since this is your personal computer, unless you allowed them to install some kind of logging or monitoring software, there's nothing for them to be able to see because they have no way to access your system.